# AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'withdraw'

Tags: python, python-3.7

I got the above error. Checked in Jupyter Notebook and removed the spaces & indentation error.
However, I continue to get the error in that terminal with the class below, despite having imported the Account class again.
If I open another terminal I don't get the error.
What do I need to ensure I don't get the error in the first Terminal window if I don't want to open a second?

```
# account.py
"""Account class definition."""
from decimal import Decimal

class Account:
    """Account class for maintaining a bank account balance."""

def __init__(self, name, balance):
    """Initialize an Account object."""

    # if balance is less than 0.00, raise an exception
    if balance < Decimal('0.00'):
        raise ValueError('Initial balance must be >= to 0.00.')

    self.name = name
    self.balance = balance

def withdraw(self, amount):
    """withdraw money from account"""

    # If amount is > balance, raise an exception
    if amount > self.balance:
        raise ValueError('withdrawl amount must <= current Balance')

    # if amount is less than 0.00, raise an exception
    elif amount < Decimal('0.00'):
        raise ValueError('withdrawl amount must be positive.')

    self.balance -= amount

def deposit(self, amount):
    """Deposit money to the account."""

    # if amount is less than 0.00, raise an exception
    if amount < Decimal('0.00'):
        raise ValueError('amount must be positive.')

    self.balance += amount
```

Comment: How did you import it?

Comment: from account import Account

Comment: Try `from importlib import reload; import account; reload(account); from account import Account`

Comment: Thanks Ry, tried all, but doesn't work. reload(account) gives <module 'account' from '/Users...ch10/account.py'> but still get the same error, having tried twice

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  It could be a `.pyc` file floating around that you can delete to get it to reload. Or it could be an indentation error (but I'm guessing that came from stackoverflow, not your code)

Comment: Apologies for not updating this earlier. The error got resolved by restarting terminal